# how to capture the output of "sort -c" in linux

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, scripting, tee

I am trying to capture the output of "sort -c" in linux. I tried redirecting it to a file, used tee command but both did not helped. Any suggestions ?

## For example:

```
roor>cat db | sort -c  
sort: -:319: disorder: 1842251880: aa bb bc dd ee
```

Following failed to give me output

```
roor>cat db | sort -c > fileName

roor>cat db | sort -c |tee fileName
```

## Sample file:

```
>cat file
111 aa as sdasd
222 sadf dzfasf af
333 sada gvsdgf h hgfhfghfg
444 asdfafasfa     gsdgsdg sgsg
222 asdasd fasdfaf asdasdasd


root>cat file |sort -c
sort: -:5: disorder: 222 asdasd fasdfaf asdasdasd

8>sort -c db 2> fileName
sort: extra operand `2' not allowed with -c

0>sort -c < file 2> result1.txt
sort: open failed: 2: No such file or directory
```

ANY ALTERNATE TO SORT -C would ALSO WORK FOR ME!!

Comment: Please check sort -c with my sample file.

Comment: I want to fine where sorting is going bad.

Comment: `-o, --output=FILE`: write result to FILE instead of standard output

Comment: As an aside: `cat file | something` is much less efficient than `something <file` (which can also be written as `<file something` if you prefer that style). Doubly so if `something` is a command like `sort` which can do optimizations that involve seeking around in its input stream when that stream is seekable (though it never needs to do so with `-c`).

Comment: @Jongware, the `-o` option isn't universal.  In particular, OSX (even recent versions) ships with GNU sort version 5.93, which does not include the option.  (Not sure why they haven't caught up with FreeBSD's sort, but there you go.)

Answer (score 4):

If `sort -c` is producing an error, it sends that error to "standard error" (`stderr`), not to "standard output" (`stdout`).

In shell, you need to use special redirects to capture standard error.

```
sort -c inputfile > /path/to/stdout.txt 2> /path/to/stderr.txt
```

These two output streams are called "file descriptors", and you can alternately redirect one of them to the other:

```
sort -c inputfile > /path/to/combined.txt 2>&1
```

You can read more about how these work [at tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html), in [the Bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html), the [bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection) and [the Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FileDescriptor).  Happy reading!  :-D

Answer (score 1):

other good alternative for '2>' is STDERR pipe

> **|&**

```
cat db | sort -c -h |& tee >fileName
```

Some time it is very suitable when present STDIN, for example:

```
TIMEFORMAT=%R;for i in `seq 1 20` ; do time kubectl get pods -l app=pod >/dev/null ; done |& sort -u -h
```

or

```
TIMEFORMAT=%R;for i in `seq 1 20` ; do time kubectl get pods >>log1  ; done |& sort -u -h
```

Answer (score 0):

`sort -c` has no output as you might expect:

```
[root@home:~] cat /etc/services | sort -c
sort: -:2: disorder: #
```

As described by the [manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/sort/), the -c argument simply checks whether a given file or input is sorted or not.

If you're trying to catch the message from the command, try redirecting the error stream (2), not the standard output (1):

```
cat file | sort -c 2>result.txt
```

Comment: Please check sort -c with my sample file.

Comment: I want to find where sorting is going bad.

Comment: just edited my answer, please see the second paragraph.

Comment: Is it documented anywhere that these checks write to `stderr`?

Comment: tried that as well but it did not helped me
/temp 581>cat file | sort -c 2>result.txt
sort: open failed: 2: No such file or directory

Comment: @user2809888, please avoid including your prompt in messages, and quote output separately from the command. It's hard to tell *exactly* what you ran, but it looks like it was somehow written in a way that referred to a file named 2, rather than a file descriptor 2. Adding an extra space in the wrong place would do that.

Comment: @user2809888, ...by the way, I would suggest instead: `sort -c <file 2>result.txt`; avoiding the pipe on stdin makes things that much more efficient. And, again, be sure you get the command exactly right -- no spaces added where they don't exist in what we're giving you here.

Comment: root@promt>sort -c db 2> fileName
sort: extra operand `2' not allowed with -c

Answer (score 0):

`sort -c`only checks if the input is sorted. It does not performs any sorting.

See: `man sort`

Remove `-c` to sort the lines.

PS: It gives the "disorder" error because the file of yours isn't already sorted. On line 5, "222" appears after "444" on the previous line.

EDIT: I think I misunderstood.
To redirect the error to a file you must use `2>`.

So, the command would become: `roor>cat db | sort -c 2> fileName`

EDIT2: You can simply use: `sort -c db 2> fileName`

Comment: I do not want any sorting, I want to find where sorting is wrong in the file.

Comment: @user2809888, if that's what you want, you should specify it clearly in your question. Error logging isn't "output" as such, so a request to redirect output from a command that doesn't have output doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, perhaps that need for clarity is a matter of perspective.  I thought the OP was pretty clear that he was trying to deal with the output of `sort -c`, rather than trying to figure out how to use the `sort` command.

Comment: @ghoti, eh? I didn't interpret as "trying to figure out how to use the sort command"; it's the use of the word "output" that's at issue. Though, granted, if that issue was the core of the misunderstanding, it's not fair to ask someone to ask a question in a way that implies that they already understand its answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, that's it exactly. Unix commands aren't always perfect, and  to be fair, I would say "error text" is merely output that goes to a different file descriptor.  In the case of `sort -c`, and *I* certainly can't explain with any authority the rationale that puts this useful diagnostic output on stderr rather than stdout.

Comment: @ghoti, this behavior reads as clearly correct to me -- the text is metadata, not data, and doesn't comply with any specification for data emitted from `sort`. In particular, it goes through localization, making it unsuitable for non-human usage without care and caution.